# Preload .ko file to linux file system

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, mmap

I have a very slow emulation system in  which linux takes much time to boot.
I want to develop a device driver on this system but rebooting it to add a modified .ko every time is not an option.

What I am looking for is a way to update my .ko file without rebooting. I should mention I don't have any external interface except DRAM so I'm using ramfs

I can however pause the system and inject any content to DRAM. So I'm thinking maybe I can load the .ko to predefined memory area and map it so I can use it from the file system

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're building a pretty crazy kernel, it's going to support dynamic kernel modules which can be loaded, unloaeded, and reloaded at runtime right?   Just inject the new kernel driver and unload/reload the module, I'd think.

The challenging part appears to be finding the new module in memory.  I suppose though, if you knew exact size and physical memory offset of the module in memory, you could read it out of /dev/mem if your kernel supports that, and write into a file of your choice.

Comment: I can inject it to memory but how can I Make the file system see the file ?  Something like reverse mmap ?

Comment: I think to answer that question we might need more details of what injecting into memory means.  If your emulator is networked, that would be another solution - just grab it over the net.  Or drop it from some other type of storage, if that's an option.  But if you need to inject directly to memory ... you might be beyond my knowledge on the subject.  I'd think you'd need a kernel space handler to 'find' a file at a certain point in memory, but that's hardly even a hunch.

Comment: To simplify, think of the system like a cpu with only DRAM and a HW debugger attached. The debugger allows to stop the system and load external files to physical memOry. If I could load it to a /dev/ram1 device I could maybe mount that device

Comment: That's a good option! I can dd from /dev/mem to a file on the file system and then use it. Thanks .

Comment: BTW - maybe you should add that as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Good call, I added this to the answer.  I'd be interested in whether you get it working too!

Comment: I'm able to create the file and it looks right. Still didn't try to load it to the kernel.

Comment: pretty awesome though nonetheless.